# Is a 99% upper confidence bound the upper limit of a 99% confidence interval?

Tags: probability, statistics, confidence-interval

I have to find a "99% confidence bound" for a standard deviation.  This is not hard.  The only question I have is whether this is finding the $\chi^2_{.99}$ value or just the upper bound for the 99% confidence interval (between $\chi^2_{.005}$ and $\chi^2_{.995}$).  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks in advanced!

Comment: $\chi^2_{0.99}$. Th wording asks for that, and not for a symmetric confidence interval. For the variance in particular, one is seldom interested in a confidence interval in the small tails on both sides sense.

Answer (score 1):

The *upper confidence bound* would be the $\chi^2_{0.99}$ value.  As a Google seach will show, the term is in fairly common use, and has a standard meaning: "the" point $a$ such that $F_X(a)=0.99$, the point that has $1\%$ of the area in the right tail.

In particular, the $99\%$ upper confidence bound is **not** the upper limit of a $99\%$ confidence interval with $0.005$ in each tail.

For variance particularly, upper confidence bounds are the usual quantity of interest. One wants protection against the variance being "too large."